# Can numpy arrays run in GPUs?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, gpu

I am using PyTorch. I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import torch

X = np.array([[1, 3, 2, 3], [2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4]])
X = torch.DoubleTensor(X).cuda()

X_split = np.array_split(X.numpy(), 
                         indices_or_sections = 2, 
                         axis = 0)
X_split
```

but I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-870b5d3f67b6> in <module>()
----> 1 X_prime_class_split = np.array_split(X_prime_class.numpy(), 
      2                                      indices_or_sections = 2,
      3                                      axis = 0)
      4 X_prime_class_split

TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.
```

The error message is clear and I know how to fix this error by just including `.cpu()`, ie. `X_prime_class.cpu().numpy()`. I am just curious to know if this confirms that numpy arrays cannot run in GPUs/Cuda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you cannot generally run numpy functions on GPU arrays. PyTorch reimplements much of the functionality in numpy for PyTorch tensors. For example [`torch.chunk`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.chunk.html) works similarly to `np.array_split` so you could do the following:

```
X = np.array([[1, 3, 2, 3], [2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4]])
X = torch.DoubleTensor(X).cuda()
X_split = torch.chunk(X, chunks=2, dim=0)
```

which splits `X` into multiple tensors without ever moving the `X` off the GPU.